# Save dynamically created layout on screen rotation

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

I am creating a layout dynamically when the activity first starts, the problem is when the screen is rotated it is hitting the database again to create the layout.  How can I save the layout so it isn't recreated each time the screen orientation is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!  Created a fragment and load an ArrayList of the views that are getting dynamically created during onCreate.  Set setRetainInstance(true); and onPause clear the views and onResume reload the views from the ArrayList.  With setRetainInstance(true), onCreate will not be called again so it will not load from the DB.

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' (using the green checkmark) to enable others to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs for overriding the default rotation behavior: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: onRetainNonConfigurationInstance has been deprecated. Trying to use fragments but will not retain the dynamically loaded views.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // SAVE YOUR DATA IN "outstate" BUNDLE
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // RESTORE YOUR DATA FROM savedInstanceState.
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

save data bundle and restore it again in onRestoreInstanceState

here is example..

```
public class Test_stflowActivity extends Activity {
    String initial_text = null;
    boolean already_created = false;
    TextView tv = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            initial_text = "bharat";
            loadNew();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        initial_text = "sharma";
        outState.putString("initial_text", initial_text);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        initial_text = savedInstanceState.getString("initial_text");
        loadNew();
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    void loadNew() {
        tv.setText(initial_text);
    }
}
```

here is xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="139dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout
```

>

Comment: But how can you save Views to a bundle?

Comment: You need not to save view every time when you rotate your device it will call on create again. you can reapply your data on your views by restoring them. In this way your views will recreate and your previous data will automatically set..

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow.  On a rotate the setContentView gets called and wipes out my dynamically added Views.

Comment: (I can't get this to format, sorry)<br/>
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    
  setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
  
  if (savedInstanceState == null){
   //Load all layout data from the database
   loadNew();
  }
  
  getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
  
}

Comment: remove this if case and try if (savedInstanceState == null) and dont use save intance and restore instance check it..

Comment: loadNew opens the database and loads the Views dynamically, that is what I'm trying to get away from.

Comment: I have created test project in that I have kept example look at that.. it will help you..

Comment: loadNew is creating the view not just setting the text.  CheckBox chk = new CheckBox(context);

Comment: you are using android:configChanges="orientation" in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

In new versions, you might disable Activity layout destroy with such as mentioned here (instead of deprecated features):
[android:configChanges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71891158/15428205)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).