# setRetainInstance is deprecated. What is alternative?

Tags: android, deprecated

setRetainInstance is deprecated. What alternative?

I have a lot of fragments with many complicated object variables inside them.
Today I only have one line of code: `setRetainInstance`.
Full code example is below:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
    private MyComplicatedCustomClass1 object1;
    private MyComplicatedCustomClass2 object2;
    private MyComplicatedCustomClass3 object3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }
}
```

This is more than enough to forget about saving and restoring my objects when changing the configuration (for example, when changing the screen rotation).

What should I change in my code for replacing `setRetainInstance`?

**Please give me a short code example, if possible.**

P.S.

**ATTENTION:**
I can read the documentation - so please don't answer in a Google-style manner:
"ViewModel is the best... google recommend... and bla-bla...".
And please don't copy/paste articles from Google documentation - I can view it myself.

If you have a concrete working code solution - I will very appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I set configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml instead of setRetainInstance in fragment. Activity does not destroy my fragment and objects in it when I flip the orientation.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution recommended by Google, consists of using a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel), where you'd not only maintain (and restore) the state, but also asyncrhonously push [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) (or similar).
There's also now an additional simple semi-automatic solution in the form of the [Saved State Module for ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate).

To Quote:

> When using this module, ViewModel objects receive a SavedStateHandle object through its constructor. This object is a key-value map that lets you write and retrieve objects to and from the saved state. These values persist after the process is killed by the system and remain available through the same object.

So you should always assume your Fragment (and its UI) are temporary, and will be destroyed at the operating system's earliest convenience.
It's up to you to ensure it doesn't depend on state being "magically saved" (like setRetainInstance), and instead write your Fragment in a way where it restores its state based on what the ViewModel offers.

Comment: If you think there's a magic solution (short of what I already provided) then you will be disappointed. You have a lot of "complex objects" that you lazily don't want to save in the correct reusable and testable way? fine, then keep your complex objects in you UI, but then don't come asking if there's a magic solution (because there is none). Set Retain instance was not a solution, was a hack. You don't need to restore a state, if you never destroy it...

Comment: The problem here is that on slow Android devices recreating complex UI from complex ViewModel takes a LONG time. Like I might have an autocompletetextview that user had opened then they rotate the screen and that list of options is closed. On iOS the OS gives it to you for free. This is where the frustration comes from.

Comment: It's true that this will be "slower", but the previous solution was NOT to destroy the fragment (retain), which can have other side-effects and we're not going to go into that conversation here. The Google-Recommended solution is that one, alternatively the OP can replicate the "setRetain" logic themselves and deal with the consequences. Google doesn't really care that much about "older/slow" devices, /shrug

Comment: There is a reason it is so much nicer to develop for iOS :)

Comment: Yes, especially the part where you can only do it on macOS (which to some people is a disaster), potentially 99% of developers are stuck with Xcode or have to use it one way or another, and you have to roll the die to see if the App Store review will let you even publish your app. ;) On a device that is less than 5 years old, the Android experience has no such issue, the speed is plenty to recreate the views on time. The same happens on the iPhone 6s that I use for testing, it's terribly slow and modern apps (if supported) crash often due to OOM errors. /shrug. tl;dr: both platforms suck.

Answer (score -1):

You can either use liveData or other kind of ViewModeling, or use `arguments` in order to set extras to your classes. Listeners can be set in the `onAttach` method.

If you are using `retainInstance` a lot you are probably having several memory leaks.

Fragments shouldn't be that complex, so if you have fragments with several classes that are complex maybe you should check your architecture.